Why doesn't my email sent via Python use CSS correctly?
I tried to send emails via smtplib. It correctly works with others' html/css code, but works incorrectly in my case. Here's my Python code:
smtp_server = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
smtp_server.starttls()
smtp_server.login(email, password)

message = EmailMessage()
message["From"] = email
message["To"] = recipient
message["Subject"] = "Test"
with open("test.html", "r") as file:
    text = file.read()

message.set_content(text, subtype="html")

smtp_server.send_message(message)
smtp_server.quit()

Here's my HTML code:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <style type="text/css">
.email-confirmation {
  background-color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  max-width: 480px;
  width: 100%;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: #000;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 91px 69px 330px;
  font: 15px Inter, sans-serif;
}

.logo {
  aspect-ratio: 7.81;
  object-fit: contain;
  object-position: center;
  width: 179px;
  align-self: center;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.confirmation-title {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 600;
  align-self: start;
  margin-top: 51px;
}

.confirmation-message {
  font-weight: 300;
  margin-top: 24px;
}

.confirmation-code {
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 30px;
  background-color: #000;
  align-self: center;
  margin-top: 55px;
  width: 215px;
  max-width: 100%;
  font-size: 35px;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 700;
  padding: 7px 35px;
}

.signature {
  font-weight: 500;
  align-self: start;
  margin-top: 40px;
}
</style>

<section class="email-confirmation">
  <img loading="lazy" src="url">
  <h1 class="confirmation-title">Подтверждение почты</h1>
  <p class="confirmation-message">
    Это письмо отправлено, чтобы <br />
    подтвердить электронную почту. <br />
    <br />
    Если это были не Вы, проигнорируйте данное письмо. <br />
    <br />
    Для завершения подтверждения - <br />
    вернитесь к боту и введите этот код.
  </p>
  <div class="confirmation-code" tabindex="0" role="textbox" aria-label="Confirmation code">173 586</div>
  <p class="signature">С уважением, команда Bard!</p>
</section>
</body>
</html>

If I open the file via a browser, the CSS loads correctly, but in Gmail, it doesn't.
Browser view

Gmail view

What can I do to resolve this?

For one thing, the <style> tag should be inside the <head> section, not the <body> section.

This is because you have a fundamental flaw in your understanding. Email clients like Gmail are not web browsers. They do not render code according to normal web standards. They are a law to themselves.
You need to check https://caniemail.com for what Gmail can use.
Also note that if it works on Gmail, it's not necessarily going to work on other email clients.
You might prefer to get snippets already tried and tested as there are lots out there.
